# Thick line problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, line

TikZ draws thin line instead of thick line. Two lines in the code seems same.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.15cm,y=0.15cm,z=0cm]
\draw[thick] (-20,5,0) -- (40,5,0);
\draw[thin] (-20,2,0) -- (40,2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tested your code and the lines have different thickness... Probably your pdf viewer needs some zoom (or try another one)

Comment: As @koleygr says, it's probably your PDF viewer or printer. This said, there are many different thicknesses that you can use from `ultra thin` to `ultra thick` -- see section 15.3.1 of the manual. You can also set the thickness manually  with `\draw[line width=5mm](-20,5,0) -- (40,5,0);`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP doesn't seem to answering about the comments and his/her problem is not really a latex (but probably a viewer) problem

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I checked it double. But still thin line.

Comment: @Void did you tried to open it with another pdf viewer? If so which viewers did you tried? Did you zoomed enough? Did you tried to replace `thick` by `ultra thick`?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I am going to try it and inform here.

Comment: @koleygr Give people some time to react before closing

Comment: @percusse You are right... I just seen that the OP had seen more than once the comments and did not answer... The vote was almost an hour after the first comment and he had seen that enough time before answer... I just thought he will never answer and that the problem solved. But You are right anyway....

Comment: I tried. [thick] doesn't work. [line width=0.5mm] works perfect. BTW, many people in this "Stack" community have mental problems. What is the hurry? What is that arrogance? ... OK. I'll delete all my Stack accounts like StackOverflow.

Comment: @koleygr Well done for your on hold ego boost. How can I give you more points? I can do for you if you'd be happy.

Comment: @Void I am sorry... It was stupid from me to vote so early (I just supposed that you will never answer.) If you see my answers today, you will find answer that have been seen and not even commented... but the op went to the next question... got another answer... and would not even comment there too if not had a problem. I just supposed you will not even answer because you realized that the mistake was the viewer (that it sure was). Anyway... Sorry again... I can vote to reopen and it probably would in minutes... But I am sure that it is a viewer problem and thus only it may remain clesed

Comment: @Void, Didn't show your last comment... And you can learn that I dont get points by closing posts... Anyway I can understand (somehow) your feelings on this... Do you want me to vote to reopen? (The only problem I see on this is that your answer that line width works but thick doesn't means that probably a zoom would solve the problem)

Comment: Nothing to sorry. Not personal. Whole Stack system sucks. I'm enough for Stack Overflow and whole Stack community. Every serious question is downvoted. I'll migrate somewhere else . One person less. Best wishes.